# Не устанавливается Gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm

Всем привет. Столкнулся вот с такой проблемой. На рабочий комп не хочет устанавливаться gulp.
NodeJS установлен.
Вот такие ошибки выходят:

```
1382 error code ENOENT
1383 error syscall lstat
1384 error path C:\Users\Maratkanov.IUS\AppData\Roaming\npm
1385 error errno -4058
1386 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Maratkanov.IUS\AppData\Roaming\npm'
1387 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
1388 verbose exit -4058
```

Вот скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как это лечится?
Операционка Win10

Answer (score 0):

Если устанавливаете глобально, используйте команду `sudo`:

```
sudo npm i -g gulp
```

Comment: npm i -g gulp
тоже не сработал.

вот что в командной строке отобразилось:
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.

changed 352 packages, and audited 352 packages in 35s

Comment: 7 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

9 vulnerabilities (4 low, 5 moderate)

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.

Команда gulp -v отдаёт опять
bash: gulp: command not found


P.S. Как вставить в комментарий картинку, или код - не знаю, такого инструментария видать stackoverflow не предоставляет, что странно, т.к. при создании вопроса такой функционал есть.